# jQuery get data from REST service

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

i have implemented REST service which is hosted on address `http://localhost:8080/rest/adrestresource/1.0/activedirectory/findgroups%20test@lab.local%20`pwds%20localhost . This service is visible and accesible (i can get xml from it using web browsers), but i am no able to write simple jquery script which will get data and displays it. My code:

```
$.ajax({                     
                      url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/adrestresource/1.0/activedirectory/findgroups%20test@lab.local%20Bezhesla1%20localhost",
                       //url:  'http://api.geonames.org/astergdem?lat=50.01&lng=10.2&username=demo&style=full&type=XML',
                      type: 'GET',
                      dataType: 'xml',
                      success: function(xml){
                              alert('success');                                                           
                        }



                    });
```

When i change address to another rest service, alert popup appears (which means that problem is in REST service path). Any ideas what is wrong? :)

REST service is implemented as Atlassian JIRA plugin deployed on local jira instance :)

Comment: Try `data` parameters in this, you can't directly pass the parameters in URL you have to use `data` attribute of jQuery ajax request.

Comment: You have error in your code, redundant `);` after sucess callback function.

Comment: Did you check for Same Origin Policy violation? what is the uri of the page making this request

Comment: Typo in code ); after alert();

Comment: i have repaired wrong parenthesis :)

Comment: What exactly does Same origin policy means? Rest rervice is running on localhost, and i am accesing it via web browser from same computer :) Probably it is worth mentioning that REST service is implemented as Atlassian JIRA plugin and deployed on local jira instance :)

Comment: Did you enable cross domain calls? This would explain that it is working in browser, but not on this page.

Comment: I didnt enabled cross domain calls, how can i do that? :)

Comment: You say ***Rest rervice is running on localhost, and I am accessing it via web browser from same computer.*** They will be at the same domain if the REST service is at `http://localhost:8080/...` and the web page is also at `http://localhost:8080/...`. Does not matter if you access that page from the local computer or not. If you are opening the web page from just clicking on it on the file explorer, the page's URL is `file://X:/somefolder/...`  and thus not `http://localhost:8080/...`, so... other domain: CORS support is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable cross-domain XHR requests put `jQuery.support.cors = true;` in a the js code. I usually add it to a `<script>` block right before `</body>.`

Answer (score 1):

Try `data` parameters in this, you can't directly pass the parameters in URL you have to use data attribute of jQuery ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '"http://localhost:8080/rest/adrestresource/1.0/activedirectory/findgroups',
            data: {argu1: 'data1', argu2: 'data2', argu3: 'data3'},
            contentType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                  alert('success');                                                           
            });
           }

        })
```

Comment: this probably wont be a problem, because i can use call service http://api.geonames.org/astergdem?lat=50.01&lng=10.2&username=demo&style=full&type=XML and it works. Probably it is worth mentioning that REST service is implemented as Atlassian JIRA plugin and deployed on local jira instance :)